# XSLT: :result-document

Tags: xslt

I have an XSL which generates a XML file

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"> 
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/> 
  <xsl:template match="/"> 
    <xsl:variable name="filename" select="concat('TextTypes','.html')" />
    <xsl:result-document method="html" href="{$filename}">
      <font name="{$truncatedFont}" size="{$truncatedSize}" style="{@styleOverride}" env="{$env}" lang="{@language}" />
    </xsl:result-document>    
  </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I run the XSLT i get the error:

```
ERROR:  'Unsupported XSL element 'http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform:result-document''
Error during transformation
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported XSL element 'http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform:result-document'
```

I have specified ny XSLT verision as 2.0. I am confused on why i get this error. Please help.

Answer (score 4):

XSLT 2.0  is only supported by a few XSLT processors, I think with Java there is only [Saxon 9](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/) and with IBM's websphere you can also use IBM's XSLT 2.0 processor but the XSLT processor in the Oracle respectively SUN JRE and JDK is based an Apache Xalan and only supports XSLT 1.0.

Comment: In such cases, is there a way I can output multiple files from XSLT using version 1.0? Can i achieve this using XSLT 1.0?

Comment: Pure XSLT 1.0 does not have any such feature to create multiple output files. If I understand http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/extensionslib.html#redirect correctly then Xalan has an extension to allow that. I would however suggest to consider to move to Saxon and XSLT 2.0, see http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/using-xsl/embedding/jaxp-transformation.xml or for a new API catering for XSLT 2.0 http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/using-xsl/embedding/s9api-transformation.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your xslt processor does not support version 2.0.

Comment: How do i set a xslt processor so that i can get this working?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you're running your XSLT nishMaria.

If you can daisy chain XSLT then you can process the input document multiple times to produce multiple different output files or produce one output file with all the desired output then pass this file through a number of XSLT's each of which just selects part of the output.