# How to use same XML source document for multiple webpages using XSL

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm sorry if my question is too easy and doesn't belong here. I am working on an assignment and I have an XML source document with an stylesheet declaration linking to an XSL that outputs as HTML. Right now that all works fine, however this page needs to be a link on a different page. This other page (I'm assuming I will code it as a simple HTML file) also needs a second link that will perform some calculations using information from the same XML source document I'm already using. I think I'm missing something simple, but how can I create another page using the same XML?

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="cookies.xsl" ?>
<cookies>
<cookie>
    <brand>Oreo</brand>
    <name>Double Stuff</name>
    <nutritional_info>
        <calories>150</calories>
        <fat>20</fat>
        <sugar>5</sugar>
        <protein>1</protein>
    </nutritional_info>
</cookie>
<cookie>
    <brand>Oreo</brand>
    <name>Golden Oreo</name>
    <nutritional_info>
        <calories>190</calories>
        <fat>7.6</fat>
        <sugar>13.7</sugar>
        <protein>1.5</protein>
    </nutritional_info>
</cookie>
    <cookie>
    <brand>Oreo</brand>
    <name>Sandwich Cookie</name>
    <nutritional_info>
        <calories>140</calories>
        <fat>7.0</fat>
        <sugar>13.0</sugar>
        <protein>1.0</protein>
    </nutritional_info>
</cookie>
<cookie>
    <brand>Archway</brand>
    <name>Dutch Cocoa</name>
    <nutritional_info>
        <calories>110</calories>
        <fat>3.6</fat>
        <sugar>16.0</sugar>
        <protein>1.1</protein>
    </nutritional_info>
</cookie>
```

XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method ="html" version="4.0" />
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Cookies</title>
            <link href="cookies.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1 id="header"><img src="header.jpg" alt="cookies" height="150" width="100%"/></h1>
            <h1>Nutritional Info</h1>
            <h2 id="n_info">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="cookies/cookie"/>
            </h2>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="cookie">
    <h2><xsl:value-of select="@brand"/> <xsl:value-of select="name"/></h2>
    <xsl:for-each select=".">
            <p><img src="{name}.jpg" id="picture"/>                 
            </p>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="nutritional_info"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="nutritional_info">
    <table border="1" id="info">
        <tr>
            <th>Calories</th>
            <th>Protein</th>
            <th>Total Fat</th>
            <th>Sugar</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="calories"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="protein"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="fat"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="sugar"/>
        </tr>
    </table>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="calories|protein|fat|sugar">
    <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
</xsl:template>
```

I want to make a link that will open the xml using this stylesheet, and then another link that will apply different styles and templates but using the same information from the same XML file.

Comment: "how can I create another page using the same XML" - I'd recommend writing some **XSLT** to transform some **input XML** into **output HTML**. If you already have those 3 things, perhaps you could show us and we could help some more.

Comment: I didn't think it mattered, but updated the OP with that information.

Comment: Of course it matters. We need to see your code to diagnose the issue. Now, what is this code not doing that it should?

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr Please read the question, it is quite clear (and was clear from the beginning).

Comment: See if this helps: http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_client.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve this: dynamic input files, using XSLT 2.0 functionality or simply having two XML files.

**Dynamic input**

If you are creating your input XML file dynamically (i.e. refreshing it when an event takes place), ensure that this line:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="cookies.xsl" ?>
```

refers to the correct XSLT stylesheet, according to which link has been clicked on.

**XSLT functionality**

Else, it is possible to output several HTML files from within the same stylesheet, using the `result-document()` function. However, this is an option only if you have XSLT 2.0 at your disposal (see: [XSLT: :result-document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9823725/xslt-result-document)). Judging from your stylesheet, I assume that you do not work with an XSLT 2.0 processor.

Even if XSLT 1.0 does not cover outputting multiple files, EXSLT does (see e.g.: [Splitting XML into multiple files with XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4036233/splitting-xml-into-multiple-files-with-xslt)).

**Duplicate and rename your XML**

As a last resort, manipulate your input XML by hand. Duplicate the XML data and alter the referral line quoted above. See to it that `cookies1.xml` contains

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="cookies1.xsl" ?>
```

and that `cookies2.xml` contains

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="cookies2.xsl" ?>
```

---

Note that this problem arises only because you hard-code a reference to a stylesheet in your XML file.